# How to make raster cells with a certain value stand out in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to make my raster cells glow in QGIS. If I have a dataset where only a few pixels has a value, they can be pretty difficult to spot (unless I know where to look). Stretching helps a bit, but one pixel still occupies one pixel on the screen (or none at all if downsampling removed it), and I would like it to stand out.

Is there a method or a plugin that can do this in QGIS?

Comment: Is extracting them as vectors an option?

Comment: or changing some values in the neighborhood of the pixel to display a "transition" ?

Comment: I'm working with datasets with billions of pixels, so I would prefer not to vectorize or create a seperate dataset for visualisation purposes. Further more, it would be neat with something working in screen space :)

Comment: Even if you can get them to glow the appropriate colour, you may not still see them unless the scale is correct... converting just the cells you're after to point would make them stand out at any scale...

Comment: I'm wondering, though can't seem to figure out, how to set the symbology for a particular value in a raster layer...

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to buffer the cells you're interested in. You could do this as a raster, or convert to a vector first (see steps below):

1. Convert your raster to a vector. `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)`
2. Buffer the new layer. `Vector > Geoprocessing > Buffer`

Adjust buffer distances and symbology to preference.

If you need to keep them as a raster, try the `r.buffer` command in GRASS GIS, which can be used via the GRASS GIS plugin in QGIS (if you have it installed).